# Updating plugins after p2 repository generation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I build my product after p2 is generated I update my branding plugin. In branding plugin I change some information which is available only after p2 generation, for example version in plugin.properties. As a result when I want to update previous version of the product I get error about md5 mismatch since md5 for plugin in p2 is different from what's been generated. A quick workaround in this situation is to edit artifacts.xml in artifacts.jar to remove 'download.md5' property for the plugin that changed. This is manual process and I'd like to avoid it if possible. Can I instruct somewhere not to generate 'download.md5' or perhaps regenerate its value after I did my modifications? Perhaps there are other solutions for this?

I can of course automate manual process and open artifacts.jar and modify artifacts.xml, but wanted to know if I can avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, I need to call p2.process.artifacts to rebuild p2 after changing plugin data.